# One to many correlation calculation in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, pearson-correlation

Trying to calculate correlation of a specific gene (Here its Gene 1) with all others (35999 candidates) in a matrix

```
         samp1   samp2   samp3   samp4
Gene 1  3.7891  2.4487  1.1939  0.6013
Gene 2  1.4484  3.2316  2.841   1.9545
Gene 3  0.4505  2.6062  2.0729  0.6403
.
.
Gene 36000  1.8828  5.2633  2.7552  1.7335
```

I used the following code

```
library(Hmisc)
A <- read.table("C:/Users/Desktop/exp.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
cor <- rcorr(as.matrix(A), type="pearson")


write.csv(cor$r,'C:/Users/Desktop/pCC VALUES.csv')
write.csv(cor$P,'C:/Users/Desktop/p VALUES.csv')
```

But the above code is for matrix calculation of 36000*36000. However, I would like to get **one to many** correlation where the gene of interest is always the first gene. Here its gene 1. This would save the processing time. One method is obviously extract the 36000 pairs of my interest from the output. I would like to know if any other method is possible to find correlation of my gene against all others without **many to many** calculation.

Edit:

I am looking for output like in the format,

```
Gene 1 Gene 2   pcc  p-value
Gene 1 Gene 3   pcc  p-value
.
.
Gene 1 Gene 36000 pcc p-value
end
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 1-to-many in this context? You want to take the 4 samples of Gene1 and correlate those to the 35999 other groups of 4 samples, one at a time? If so, there is no 1-to-many, it's 35999 one-to-one samples. But maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @DominicComtois  I agree that it is confusing to use 'one to many' term. I edited the post and added output format I am looking for. Expecting almost same result  with the above code but it should limit to PCC pairs for gene 1 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right (correlating first row with every other single row, taken one at a time), something along those lines might get you started:

```
dat <- as.matrix(read.table(text = "samp1;samp2;samp3;samp4
Gene 1;3.7891;2.4487;1.1939;0.6013
Gene 2;1.4484;3.2316;2.841;1.9545
Gene 3;0.4505;2.6062;2.0729;0.6403
Gene 4;0.4705;2.4062;1.0729;0.6003
Gene 5;1.8828;5.2633;2.7552;1.7335", sep=";"))

corr_list <- list()

for (i in 2:nrow(dat)) {
  r <- cor.test(dat[1,], dat[i,])
  corr_list[[paste("Genes 1 &", i)]] <- c(r$estimate, p.val=r$p.value)
}


# Results
corr_list

$`Genes 1 & 2`
       cor      p.val 
-0.3070573  0.6929427 

$`Genes 1 & 3`
       cor      p.val 
-0.1417635  0.8582365 

$`Genes 1 & 4`
       cor      p.val 
0.04777015 0.95222985 

$`Genes 1 & 5`
      cor     p.val 
0.1425788 0.8574212
```

You can also put results in a data.frame if more convenient:

```
corr_list <- data.frame(Gene1=numeric(), Gene2=numeric(), cor=numeric(), p.value=numeric())

for (i in 2:nrow(dat)) {
  r <- cor.test(dat[1,], dat[i,])
  corr_list[i-1,] <- c(1, i, r$estimate, r$p.value)
}

corr_list

  Gene1 Gene2         cor   p.value
1     1     2 -0.30705735 0.6929427
2     1     3 -0.14176355 0.8582365
3     1     4  0.04777015 0.9522299
4     1     5  0.14257884 0.8574212
```